# php perl script can not run using shell_exec

Tags: php, perl, shell-exec

i am trying to execute perl script using php shell_excel function. but instead of printing output it ask to open perl file when i execute php script.

i tried below

```
$result = shell_exec('app.pl');
```

app.pl contains below script

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl

$count = 0;
while (<stdin>) {
    @w = split;
    $count++;
    for ($i=0; $i<=$#w; $i++) {
    $s[$i] += $w[$i];
    }
}

for ($i=0; $i<=$#w; $i++) {
    print $s[$i]/$count, "\t";
}

print "\n";

print "hi";
```

any suggestion ?

Comment: why not run all that in php in the first place?

Comment: What do you mean by "it ask to open perl file"?

Comment: @ikegami I think it tries to download the file instead of executing it. @amit try running perl and pass the script as an argument: `shell_exec('perl app.pl')`

Comment: @ob-ivan i tried but still not display anything

Comment: What is the result of `var_dump($result)`? Have you tried simplifying your perl script to just `print "hi\n"`? Do the files reside in the same folder? Do you get any output if you enable error reporting: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053424/how-do-i-get-php-errors-to-display ?

Comment: @ob-ivan yes in the script file i just keep print "hi\n"  and i display var_dump($result) it displays NULL as output.